Save messages after broadcasting to STOMP topic
I have a very simple problem where I am trying to figure out how to post a message after its broadcasted to a specified destination. What I want to happen is to use @PostMapping annotation however I'm not sure if it's good practice to use that in conjunction with @MessageMapping.  Below is the websocket config file used in my backend which comes from this Spring Websocket tutorial.
WebSocketController.java
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    @MessageMapping("/chatlog/{roomId}")
    public void sendMessageToRoom(@DestinationVariable String roomId, Message message) {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/chat-" + roomId, message);
    }
}

How should I approach posting the message in this situation? Should I use the @PostMapping annotation or should I make a separate call from my front end to post?
